# HSB color fill in JavaScript Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to fill some circles with HSL color, such that I can change their brightness value.
I am kind of a newb at JavaScript programming and I could not find anything about HSL color in JavaScript.
I currently have this code:

```
context.fillStyle = 'rgb(200, 100, 0)';
```

And I want to basically find an equivalent of the `rgb`-function, but with HSL.

Comment: Are you aware that HSL and HSB (AKA HSV) are different color models? HSL is white whenever `L === 100%` but HSB is white only when `B === 100%` and `S === 0%` Is your question asking for HSL or HSB

Comment: I was not aware of that difference, but I meant HSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can convert from HSV to rgb.
In canvas you can use this:

- Hexadecimal colors: `ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF";`
- RGB Colors: `ctx.fillStyle = "RGB(0,0,255)"`
- RGBA Colors: `ctx.fillStyle = "RGBA(0,0,255,0.3)";`
- HSL Colors: `ctx.fillStyle = "HSL(120,100,50)";`
- HSLA Colors: `ctx.fillStyle = "HSLA(120,100,50,0.3)";`

A function to convert from hsv to rgba looks like this:

```
function HSVtoRGB(h, s, v) {
    var r, g, b, i, f, p, q, t;
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        s = h.s, v = h.v, h = h.h;
    }
    i = Math.floor(h * 6);
    f = h * 6 - i;
    p = v * (1 - s);
    q = v * (1 - f * s);
    t = v * (1 - (1 - f) * s);
    switch (i % 6) {
        case 0: r = v, g = t, b = p; break;
        case 1: r = q, g = v, b = p; break;
        case 2: r = p, g = v, b = t; break;
        case 3: r = p, g = q, b = v; break;
        case 4: r = t, g = p, b = v; break;
        case 5: r = v, g = p, b = q; break;
    }
    return {
        r: Math.round(r * 255),
        g: Math.round(g * 255),
        b: Math.round(b * 255)
    };
}
```

Comment: When I do `context.fillStyle = 'HSL(120, 100, 50)';`, I get a black color, no matter the values.

Comment: @weisbrja try this `ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl('+ 360*Math.random() +',100%,50%)';` hsl is composed like this: `hsl(hue,saturation,lightness,alpha)` hue is an integer 0-360 on the color wheel and saturation & lightness are percentages (0-100%) indicating the strength of each component and alpha is a decimal value 0.00-1.00 indicating the opacity.

Comment: I missed the percent signs (%). Thank your!

Comment: HSB is different from HSV—why is this accepted?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a package that helps with color conversions:

[npm modern-color](https://www.npmjs.com/package/modern-color)

It enables you to parse/convert most color formats:

```
import {Color} from 'modern-color';

let c = Color.parse('rgb(200, 100, 0)');
let hsl = c.hsl;
for (let h = 0; h < 360; h += 24){
  hsl.h = h;
  console.log(hsl, Color.parse(hsl));
}
```

Actually designed for this exact use case! You can traverse any color channel in the same way and make cool effects in canvas.